# BBEdit - The authenticated save for this file failed (application error code: 20004)

Tags: text-editor, macos, bbedit

I'm trying to edit my hosts file with BBEdit 10. When I begin, it tells me to unlock the file with this message:

> **Are you sure you want to unlock "hosts"?**
>
> You aren't a member of the group "wheel".

I go ahead and unlock the file but I'm not able to save it. When I try to I get this error:

> The authenticated save for this file failed (application error code: 20004)

I can edit and save the file with TextEdit or Textmate, so I'm guessing that I *do* have the proper permissions. Why can't I save the file with BBEdit? Is it because I bought the App Store version instead of the direct download?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the App Store version is not able to do authenticated saves. From the [Bare Bones Mac App Store FAQ](http://www.barebones.com/store/macappstore.html)

> Are there any differences between the Mac App Store versions of your
>   software and the versions available directly from your web site?
>   [...]
>
> In BBEdit and TextWrangler, authenticated saves (the ability to save
>   changes to files that you do not own) and the command-line tools are
>   not available in the Mac App Store versions, in order to comply with
>   Apple’s submission guidelines.
>   [...]
>
> Authenticated saves will not be possible in versions of BBEdit or
>   TextWrangler obtained from the Mac App Store. If you desire this
>   capability, please purchase BBEdit directly from us or download
>   TextWrangler directly from us.
>
> If you have already purchased BBEdit from the Mac App store and need
>   support for authenticated saves, please [contact our customer service
>   department](http://www.barebones.com/contact/sales.html) for assistance. We will require proof of purchase from the
>   Mac App Store in order to assist you; if you include that information
>   when you write us, doing so will speed the process.

**Update:** As of version 10.1.1 there is a script that BareBones has provided to allow users of the Mac App Store version to enable this feature. More information is available on this [Auth Saves Support Page](http://www.barebones.com/support/bbedit/auth-saves.html).

Comment: Ugh. Thanks for finding that. Now I gotta go contact Barebones..

Comment: Yep. App Store apps live inside a sandbox that prevents certain types of system access, is why. It allows them to be vetted by Apple in certain ways, and to be installed, updated, and removed atomically in a way that a self-installed app that has full user rights might not.

Comment: For others who have the same problem, I contacted Barebones Support and they gave me a license for the regular version with no problems

Answer (score 5):

I emailed Bare Bones's support about a related issue, and they sent me a link to [a support page](http://www.barebones.com/support/bbedit/auth-saves.html), which provides a workaround for the MAS limitation. They provide a script you can download into BBEdit's `Application Support` directory, which adds the feature back. No need to abandon the MAS after all!

Comment: The documentation says you don’t need to restart BBEdit, but I **had to** do it with version 10.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of get around this, though it's clumsy.

- Open the file in TextWrangler, then also in TextEdit. Use text edit to make a duplicate with any filename.
- Do your changes in TextWrangler as usual. It won't let you save, so Copy the whole file, and Paste it as a complete replacement of the duplicate you made in TextEdit.
- Save the duplicate. This is the finished file.
- Go into finder and manually change the filenames to replace the old one with a new one of the exact same file name.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, but with error code 100013 (permission error related to folders). The problem was that `bbedit` can't edit files just anywhere, so the directory `~/myproject` was off limits for it.

I solved the issue by moving my project to the `~/Documents` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the script which fixes the issue is here:

http://www.barebones.com/support/bbedit/auth-saves.html

And as Rafael said, restarting BBEdit is necessary, despite the wording on barebones's site.

Comment: The script mentioned above for BBEdit works perfectly for TextWrangler as well

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem, the go around that I used was to save the file on the Desktop and then I dragged it into the restricted directory.
Closed the file on BBEdit then re-opened the file from the directory into BBEdit and it works fine.